# Maxmind GeoIP2 DB get Location region

Tags: maxmind, geoip2

I just upgraded to GeoIP2 and missing the Region field.
How can I extract the region from the CityResponse object? 
I am using GeoLite2-City.mmdb

Answer (score 0):

Got it - cityResponse.getSubdivisions() return an array of regions, most common is getting one but sometimes may contain more granular data of districts for example

Comment: Can we find regionCode using geoip2 ?